# Android application - login account

Tags: android, sqlite

i am working with my project and i find it hard to go to my main activity which is diary after I log-in..The problem is that I can't display a message saying I successfully logged in and after that proceed to creating my diary..what should I do? here's my code..

### login.class

```
package com.gomez.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class login extends Activity{
        //Declare views
    private EditText uname;
    private EditText pword;
    private Button btnlogin;
    private Button btncancel;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set Activity Layout
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        //Get EditText and Button References
        uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnlogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_enter);
        btncancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);

        //set Click Listener
        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Check Login
                final String username = uname.getText().toString();
                final String password = pword.getText().toString();


                try{
                    if(username.length()>0&& password.length()>0)
                    {
                        dbuser users = new dbuser(login.this);
                        users.open();

                        if (users.Login(username, password))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(login.this,"Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(login.this, firstpage.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(login.this,"Invalid Username/Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        users.close();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(login.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                }


            }


        });

        btncancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //close application
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

please help me..thanks

Comment: Your question is not understandable. Can you explain it little bit more?

Comment: do you mean, you are not getting the Toast messages?

Comment: Send us your code of method users.Login(username, password) there is definetly error there ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Asynctask class
[Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

In the onPostExecute method, you can show your notification then start your activity.

Comment: public boolean Login(String username, String password)throws SQLException
    {
     Cursor mCursor = Udb.rawQuery(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{username,password});
     if (mCursor != null){
      if(mCursor.getCount() > 0){
       return true;
      }
     }
     return false;
    }

Comment: i deleted try catch and it worked..the next problem was that i cannot go to the next page which is the page where the user will create the diary